# trying to send a query to powerdns and expected result not being returned

Tags: powerdns

Trying to use powerdns for enum(voip) dns queries.

I believe I have it all setup correctly.

it appears to be correct in the mysql tables

```
select * from records\G
     id: 3
     domain_id: 3
     name: 0.1.9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa
     type: NAPTR
     content: 100 10 "u" "E2U+sip" "!^.*$!sip:17033482910@10.0.0.12!" .
     ttl: 120
     prio: NULL
    change_date: NULL

 select * from domains\G
         id: 3
         name: e164.arpa
         master: 127.0.0.1
         last_check: NULL
         type: MASTER
         notified_serial: NULL
         account: NULL
```

and i can see the query based on pdns logs:

```
Jun  8 16:10:47 localhost pdns[12575]: Remote 127.0.0.1 wants '0.1.9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa|NAPTR', do = 0, bufsize = 512: packetcache MISS
Jun  8 16:10:47 localhost pdns[12575]: Query: select content,ttl,prio,type,domain_id,name from records where type='SOA' and name='0.1.9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa'
Jun  8 16:10:47 localhost pdns[12575]: Query: select content,ttl,prio,type,domain_id,name from records where type='SOA' and name='1.9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa'
Jun  8 16:10:47 localhost pdns[12575]: Query: select content,ttl,prio,type,domain_id,name from records where type='SOA' and name='9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa'
```

however my digs fail:

```
dig NAPTR @127.0.0.1  0.1.9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> NAPTR @127.0.0.1 0.1.9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 8911
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;0.1.9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa. IN    NAPTR

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun  8 16:04:28 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

I see why there are no results "type=SOA" in the mysql query, but why is trying type='SOA' and not 'NAPTR'?

The answer is based on Håkan Lindqvist's suggestions:

make records table look like this:

```
     id: 6
     domain_id: 3
     name: someServer.com
     type: SOA
     content: ns1.someDNSServer.com
     ttl: 120
     prio: NULL
     change_date: NULL
      *************************** 2. row ***************************
     id: 7
     domain_id: 3
     name: someServer.com
     type: NS
     content: ns1.someDNSServer.com
     ttl: 120
     prio: NULL
     change_date: NULL
```

Comment: Yes, with what you showed in the question it's made clear that there is no `NAPTR` record to be found; there is no chance of success. (Instead you see the supposed `NAPTR`-data mis-parsed into a `SOA` record in the negative response.)

Comment: ok thats a bit cleaner, and hope it makes sense.

Comment: Regarding the edited-in solution, the `SOA` RData looks malformatted and the owner names don't appear to match the zone name. If it helps, I can format the records differently in my answer, I just think that the standardized format is best recognized and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is not with your `NAPTR` record in itself but that PowerDNS does not consider your zone valid until it has a `SOA` record.

Disregarding the specific behavior of PowerDNS, the requirements in DNS in general is that any zone should have at least `SOA` and `NS` records at its apex.
(PowerDNS does not appear to validate the `NS` aspect of this, but failing to add these records will cause problems.)

I'm not sure it actually makes sense that you are setting up a zone for the entirety of `e164.arpa` but in more general terms, if the name of your zone is `foo.example` you'd want something like this:

```
foo.example.     7200    IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. 1 3600 1800 2419200 7200
foo.example.     7200    IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
foo.example.     7200    IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
...
```

You'll want to add these mandatory records to your zones in addition to the specific data you want.

As was noted by Michael, `2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa`is a more likely zone name (that would be *+1 703 348 2*).

In PowerDNS specific terms, if you are working directly in SQL (which is not necessarily ideal) adding this zone would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO domains (name, type) VALUES('2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa', 'MASTER');
INSERT INTO records (domain_id, name, ttl, type, content) VALUES(7, '2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa', 7200, 'SOA', 'ns1.example.com hostmaster.example.com 1 3600 1800 2419200 7200');
INSERT INTO records (domain_id, name, ttl, type, content) VALUES(7, '2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa', 7200, 'NS', 'ns1.example.com');
INSERT INTO records (domain_id, name, ttl, type, content) VALUES(7, '2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa', 7200, 'NS', 'ns2.example.com');
```

After which you would add your `NAPTR` record(s):

```
INSERT INTO records (domain_id, name, ttl, type, content) VALUES(7, '0.1.9.2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa', 7200, 'NAPTR', '...');
...
```

Comment: More likely `2.8.4.3.3.0.7.1.e164.arpa` if +1 703 348 2 is delegated to them.

Comment: I am quite a noob when it comes to DNS, so I will take an advice..

Comment: Well, the bad news is that [country code 1 hasn't even been delegated](http://enumdata.org/#1) yet, so the world will never see these records until that (eventually) happens.

Comment: Thank you for the continued comments. You are very helpful.  Why did you say "if you are working directly in SQL (which is not necessarily ideal)"?  What problems could arise?